# Variable value not getting passed in function

Tags: php, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying to push the value of variable `$woo_point` to `my Mailchimp list`. do_shortcode works fine and I can echo $woo_point successfully. The issue is that the value is not passing to Mailchimp. If I set the value of `$merge_vars['POINTS'] = "anything"`, this does pass to Mailchimp successfully. Any help appreciated.

```
$woo_point = do_shortcode('[wr_show_points]');

function whatever_function_name_user_merge_tags($merge_vars, $user) {

    global $woo_point;

    $merge_vars['POINTS'] = $woo_point;
    return $merge_vars;

}

add_filter('mailchimp_sync_user_mergetags', 'whatever_function_name_user_merge_tags', 100, 2);
```

Comment: what is $woo_point? it's an array or string?

Comment: It's a strong. do_shortcode('[wr_show_points]'); returns a number

Comment: I guess the main question is, how is the $merge_vars['POINTS'] = $woo_point; syntax incorrect?

Comment: Actually I see that the shortcode 'wr_show_points' is derived from an array. Does that make a difference?